# How can I calculate the distance added between a title and a titlerule?

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, titlesec, calculations

## Question

How can I calculate the distance after a title such that I can place a node where the title rule would go?

## Example

I would like a bar to drop from the top righthand corner of the page down to the title rule (It should align perfectly despite any changes I make in the `titlesec` definitions). Bonus to anybody who can help me get the section number lined up with the section title.

## Sample Code

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

% Title Styles
\usepackage[compact,explicit,noindentafter]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{tikz} % Absolute positioning, advanced vector graphics
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes} % Adds nodes around page boxes (e.g. body)
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,decorations} % Extensions for tikz (increase compilation time)
\usepackage{anyfontsize}


\newcommand{\tikztitlenumber}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay,baseline]
    \node [inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,anchor=base] (titlenumber) at (current page text area.north east) {#1};
    \path [fill=blue] (current page.north east) rectangle ($ (titlenumber.south east -| current page.east) + (-3mm,-\baselineskip) $);
\end{tikzpicture}}

% SECTION
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\needspace{6cm}\color{blue}\Huge\bfseries}{\tikztitlenumber{\thesection}}{0pt}{#1}[\vspace{0mm}\titlerule]

\begin{document}
\section{Hello}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Since no `tikz` experts have given a solution, here's an attempt from a non-expert...

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

% Title Styles
\usepackage[compact,explicit,noindentafter]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{tikz} % Absolute positioning, advanced vector graphics
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes} % Adds nodes around page boxes (e.g. body)
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,decorations} % Extensions for tikz (increase compilation time)
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\tikztitlebar}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay,baseline]
    \node (titlenumber) {};
    \path [fill=blue] (current page.north east) rectangle ($ (titlenumber.south east -| current page.east) + (-3mm,-0.4pt) $);
\end{tikzpicture}}

% SECTION
\titleformat{\section}[hang]
    {\needspace{6cm}\color{blue}\Huge\bfseries}
    {}
    {0pt}
    {#1\hfill\thesection\tikztitlebar}
    [\vspace{0mm}\titlerule]

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Hello}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Nice, but a couple comments: Firstly, you took the number out the TikZ node. Secondly, You did not answer the question as far as I can tell. It is a wonderful example, but the question was: "How do I calculate the distance between "Hello" and the line below it? (I know how to use TikZ.) You just subtracted .4pt, but I want that to be stored in a variable.

Comment: @macmadness86 As I said, I'm not a tikz expert...

Comment: Haha. Ok. At least you're racking up the votes :) My solution was to use tikz code for the line (instead of a horizontal rule), because this way I have precise control over the distance. I will add to question.

Comment: @macmadness86 I didn't answer for the upvotes, but just to try to help you :-)